# Maven dependency tree deep levels limitation command

Tags: java, maven

Is there any mvn command or any way to limit the dependency tree depth to show only 1 or 2 levels?

For instance, if I execute `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common` I am not interested in this 4 level dependency tree depth :
--- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ quarkus-redis-client-deployment ---

```
[INFO] io.quarkus:quarkus-redis-client-deployment:jar:999-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- io.quarkus:quarkus-vertx-deployment:jar:999-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- io.quarkus:quarkus-netty-deployment:jar:999-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]       \- io.vertx:vertx-web:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO]          \- io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common:jar:4.4.6:compile
```

I'd like to see only 2 levels :

```
[INFO]       \- io.vertx:vertx-web:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO]          \- io.vertx:vertx-bridge-common:jar:4.4.6:compile
```

Comment: You could try to add `io.vertx:vertx-web` to the `includes` separated by a `,` and see the result...